# Subversion repository on Apache with WebDAV, 301 error

Tags: apache, svn, webdav

Since updating my linux distro to openSUSE 12.2, my Subversion repositories stopped to work. Checking them out or browsing through the browser is no problem at all, but committing does not work. When I try to commit a change, the client gives me:

```
svn: E175011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175011: Repository moved permanently to 'https://example.org/repo/main/!svn/me'; please relocate
svn: E175011: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
```

On the webserver, I see something like this:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [25/Oct/2012:12:11:22 +0200] "OPTIONS /repo/main/trunk/eManager HTTP/1.1" 401 401 "-" "SVN/1.7.7 neon/0.29.6"
1.2.3.4 - my_user [25/Oct/2012:12:11:22 +0200] "OPTIONS /repo/main/trunk/eManager HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "-" "SVN/1.7.7 neon/0.29.6"
1.2.3.4 - - [25/Oct/2012:12:11:22 +0200] "POST /repo/main/!svn/me HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "SVN/1.7.7 neon/0.29.6"
```

Note: The first request is only for basic authentication. My config (in an SSL-enabled VHost, hasn't been changed since previous distro version) is as follows:

```
# main svn repo
<Location /repo/main>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /srv/svn/main

    # Require SSL connection for password protection.
    SSLRequireSSL

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Enter password"
    AuthUserFile /srv/config/.htpasswd-main
    Require valid-user

    #test
    ErrorDocument 404 default
</Location>
```

I've already read dozens of threads on this, without any working solution.
I've upgraded the subversion structure with *`svnadmin`* and I've made sure (by grep'ing) that no other Alias/Location is set to /repo (which was the most frequent suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Can't recall when and why I started to write location this way, but - I haven't troubles with 301 errors at least:

- In Location definition I use trailing /
- SVN(Parent)?Path also defined with trailing /

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. My config now looks like this, same result though:`<Location /repo/main/>` and `SVNPath /srv/svn/main/`

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:** I finally found [a helpful thread](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/40555-Post-Subversion-1-6-17-to-1-7-1-upgrade-help) which at least describes a workaround. I added this to my config and committing works again:

```
SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol off
```

This isn't perfect, though, I'd still appreciate a better answer.